# Testing this.props.navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, testing, jestjs, enzyme

```
import React from 'react';
import ListElements from '../Components/ListElements';
class HospitalsScreen extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Hospitals: ['Hospital de Base','Hospital Regional de Taguatinga','Hospital da Ceilandia','Clínica']
    };
  }

  onPressItem() {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('sectors');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ListElements
      list = {this.state.Hospitals}
      title='Hospitais'
      onPress={this.onPressItem.bind(this)}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default HospitalsScreen;
```

I'm having some trouble testing this screen in the _onPress function.
I did not find anything that solved the problem.

Comment: what is the error? can you post the navigation method or the library name you use for navigating?

Comment: I'm using react-navigation. The problem is that I can not find a way to test this, it always gives the error "cannot read property props of undefined"

Comment: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/2793.  this might help you I think

Answer (score 0):

In **Javascript** the value of `this` inside a function depends upon how that function is invoked.

Learn how the `this` binding works in JavaScript [here](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md)

There are a couple of ways to achieve it. Use them and see if you get `this` as undefined in the function or not.

One is to add  `this.onPressItem = this.onPressItem.bind(this);` in the constructor.

Another is arrow functions

`onPressItem= (event) => 
     {this.props.navigation.navigate('sectors');
}`

And then there is `onPress={this.onPressItem.bind(this)}`.

You can find more details [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/this-is-why-we-need-to-bind-event-handlers-in-class-components-in-react-f7ea1a6f93eb)

Also please go through this article [Don't Use Bind When Passing Props](https://daveceddia.com/avoid-bind-when-passing-props/)